# How can I select multiple columns for a condition with a single where statement?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am doing some outlier detection for calculations at different time horizons.

How can I clean up the following in Vertica SQL?

```
Select * FROM my_table
WHERE (    
         (expected_value * 100) > measure_10_sec 
      OR (expected_value * 100) > measure_20_sec
      OR (expected_value * 100) > measure_30_sec
      OR (expected_value * 100) > measure_40_sec
      OR (expected_value * 100) > measure_50_sec
      OR (expected_value * 100) > measure_60_sec
)
```

To a more nifty query like this:

```
Select * FROM my_table
WHERE (expected_value* 100) > (measure_10_sec, measure_20_sec, measure_30_sec, measure_40_sec, measure_50_sec, measure_60_sec)
```

Comment: What are the values of "measure_xx_sec"? If it does as it's name suggests, surely you just need (expected_value * 100) > measure_10_sec?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni - That will not work. It is possible the other measures are outliers while measure_10_sec is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `LEAST()`:

```
select * 
from my_table
where (expected_value * 100) > least(measure_10_sec, measure_20_sec, measure_30_sec, measure_40_sec, measure_50_sec, measure_60_sec)
```

If `expected_value * 100` is greater than one of the values, then it is greater than the smallest of the values.

Note:  This assumes that all the measures are non-`NULL`.

If `AND` were used instead of `OR`, then you would use `GREATEST()`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ANY` to check if the left operator satisfies an operation with any right operator from a subquery.

```
...
WHERE expected_value * 100 > ANY(SELECT measure_10_sec
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT measure_20_sec
                                 ...
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT measure_50_sec
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT measure_60_sec)
...
```

Note: I'm not sure if your DBMS supports the `SELECT` without `FROM` syntax. The documentation suggests it, but you probably need to find another subquery to get the values.